# Retorno null para método tipo List<String>

Tags: java, spring, jpa, hsqldb

Tenho um método com retorno tipo `List<String>`, ao ser feito uma query posso retorno um valor ou nada:

```
public class Repositorio {

     @PersistenceContext
      private EntityManager em;

      public List<String> listaEscritorio(Integer id){
        if(id>0) {

            Query query = em.createQuery("select * from escritorio where id="+id);
            return query.getResultList();
        }
         return null;
      }
}
```

Porém, a IDE do Java retorna erro ao tipo de retorno `null`.

**Código do Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(path ="/select2")
    public @ResponseBody List<String> Escritorios(){

        List<String> resultado = repo.listaEscritorio(3);

        return resultado;
    }
```

Quero retornar o nome de uma escritório. Estou suando uma classe repositório para efetuar as operações de consultas no banco de dados.

**Entidade Escritorio**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="escritorio")
public class Escritorio {
    @Id 
    private Long id;
    private String cnpj;
    private Long contato;
    private Long endereco;
    private String nome;
    private Long qtd_maximo_atividade;
    private Long qtd_maximo_prazo_juridico;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCnpj() {
        return cnpj;
    }
    public void setCnpj(String cnpj) {
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
    }
    public Long getContato() {
        return contato;
    }
    public void setContato(Long contato) {
        this.contato = contato;
    }
    public Long getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }
    public void setEndereco(Long endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public Long getQtd_maximo_atividade() {
        return qtd_maximo_atividade;
    }
    public void setQtd_maximo_atividade(Long qtd_maximo_atividade) {
        this.qtd_maximo_atividade = qtd_maximo_atividade;
    }
    public Long getQtd_maximo_prazo_juridico() {
        return qtd_maximo_prazo_juridico;
    }
    public void setQtd_maximo_prazo_juridico(Long qtd_maximo_prazo_juridico) {
        this.qtd_maximo_prazo_juridico = qtd_maximo_prazo_juridico;
    }

}
```

**Systen.proprierty**

```
database_url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/nome_banco
database_username=postgres
database_password=postgres
```

**Erro:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Mensagem de erro no Postman**

> {
>       "timestamp": "2018-08-02T21:19:46.019+0000",
>       "status": 500,
>       "error": "Internal Server Error",
>       "message": "No message available",
>       "path": "/monitor/escritorio" }

**Erro no eclipse**

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

**Mensagem de Erro:**

```
2018-08-02 18:20:35.905 ERROR 7368 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at controller.ControllerGeral.escritorios(ControllerGeral.java:70) ~[bin/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

Comment: Olha, pode até dar uma *warning* de [unchecked]. Também não duvidaria de ver isso sendo a causa de `ClassCastException` ou `NullPointerException`. Mas erro de compilação eu acho que não. Se ele dá algum erro, poste a mensagem de erro na pergunta.

Comment: Essa consulta sua tá toda errada:  1. por que concatenar o id e não usar parâmetro? É prática para evitar sql injection; 2. Qual provider JPA está usando? Provavelmente não é necessário checar se é maior que 0 e caso contrário retornar `null`, `Query#getResultList()`, os providers mais usados irão retornar uma lista vazia se não tiver resultado, ou retorne `Optional`; 3. evite retornar referências nulas, só servem pra causar NPEs; 4. prefira `TypedQuery`; 5. `entidade` é uma entidade JPA?; 6. qual é o erro que a IDE tá apontando?

Comment: Quero retornar o nome de uma escritório. Estou suando uma classe Repositório para efetuar as operações de consultas no banco.

Comment: Um mesmo escritório pode ter vários nomes? Como é que você mapeou essa entidade `Escritorio`?

Comment: Você esta usando maven? Coloca as configurações do pom.xml

Comment: estou usando gradlew

Comment: Você adicionou a dependencia do javax.servlet-api, na versão 3.1 pois você esta usando tomcat 8.5?

Comment: Esse problema é muito parecido com o seu: *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129725/null-pointer-exception-in-dispatcher-servlet*

Answer (score 3):

Já que você quer retornar o nome dos escritórios, presumindo que esteja usando JPA 2.2, faça isso:

```
public class Repositorio {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<String> listaEscritorio(int id) {
        return em.createQuery("select * from escritorio where id = ?", Escritorio.class)
                .setParameter("id", id)
                .getResultStream()
                .map(Escritorio::getNome)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

```
@RequestMapping(path ="/select2")
public @ResponseBody List<String> escritorios() {
    return repo.listaEscritorio(3);
}
```

Algumas observações:

- Não tem sentido o parâmetro do `listaEscritorio` ser `Integer` ao invés de `int`. No seu código original, passar um `null` nele iria dar `NullPointerException` e seria uma operação sem qualquer sentido.
- Não retorne `null` em métodos que retornam listas. Isso é pedir para ter um `NullPointerException` depois. Você pode devolver uma lista vazia.
- Como é que você acha que um `select *` poderia trazer apenas strings como resultados sendo que a tabela em questão tem pelo menos dois campos? O que você tem que fazer é uma pesquisa por entidades e então você pega o nome do escritório dessa entidade.
- Isso supõe que você tenha uma entidade `Escritorio` adequadamente mapeada e que nela há um método `getNome()` que retorna uma `String`.

**EDITADO**

No entanto, como um escritório só pode ter um único nome e você está pesquisando por `id`, logo você só retornará um único nome na lista. Assim sendo, nem tem sentido usar lista para isso:

```
public class Repositorio {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public String nomeEscritorio(int id) {
        Escritorio x = em.find(Escritorio.class, id);
        return x == null ? "" : x.getNome();
    }
}
```

```
@RequestMapping(path ="/select2")
public @ResponseBody String escritorios() {
    return repo.nomeEscritorio(3);
}
```

Comment: Em qual cenário ser `Integer` o parâmetro e passar `null` daria NPE e sem sentido? `setParameter` aceita referências nulas sem problema, talvez só não retornaria nada se o id for `not null`. Até faz sentido ser o wrapper, pra evitar boxing/unboxing desnecessário

Comment: @BrunoCésar Olha no código-fonte original dele: `if(id>0)` - Isso faria o unboxing e daria um NPE.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81074/discussion-between-alexjosesilva-and-victor-stafusa).

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você tem que "tipar" o retorno do `createQuery`. Acho que algo assim:

```
TypedQuery<String> query = em.createQuery("select * from escritorio where id="+id, String.class);
```

Deve está dando erro de casting.

Porque o `createQuery` deve está retornando um `List<Object>` ou simplesmente um `List`, e a assinatura do seu método requer uma `List<String>`.

E também esse seu código está estranho. Escritório é uma classe de persistência né? Então teria que retornar uma lista de Escritórios, não uma lista de String.

E se você quer procurar pela chave primaria, você tem que usar o `EntityManager#find();`

```
Escritorio e = em.find(Escritorio.class, id);
```

Comment: Em que versão da JPA `EntityManager#createQuery(String, Class)` retorna `Query`? É retornado `TypedQuery`, não `Query`. `createQuery` não retorna `List` de tipo nenhum, quem retorna isto são _result lists_.

Comment: Quero retornar o nome de uma escritório. Estou suando uma classe Repositório para efetuar as operações de consultas no banco.

Comment: @BrunoCésar sobre `Query`, eu só copiei o que ele pois no código dele, não conferi. Realmente `EntityManager#createQuery(String, Class)` vai retornar uma `TypedQuery<Class>`, mas esse outro erro aí foi para simplificar, o que realmente interessa para ele, no nível que ele está, é o resultado final.